# how can I compile header and its run file without main

Tags: makefile, g++

I have two files without main

- X.h
- X.cpp

I want compile these in one makefile

My makefile is ;

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS_W = -Werror -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wunused-function \
         -Wfloat-equal -Wall
CXXFLAGS_M = -ansi  -pedantic-errors
CXXFLAGS   = ${CXXFLAGS_M} ${CXFLAGS_W}

all:    main
       ./main
```

When I use like make X , compiler gives some error "undefined reference to main ". Due to that reason, I want new makefile. X can be any name .

Comment: what do you want to be the outcome? A library? An object file? You can't make an executable program without main.

Comment: I dont want executable program, just   I need; "after compiling, see error and then fix them"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally have something like:

```
X.o: X.cpp X.h
    g++ -c -o X.o X.cpp  # or $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o ...
```

with whatever other flags you needed. `-c` tells the compiler to just compile rather than compile and link, and you don't usually compile the header file directly, rather you `#include` it in the cpp file.

---

Here's a makefile which combines two separate source files into a single executable:

```
xy: x.o y.o
    g++ -o xy x.o y.o

x.o: x.cpp x.hpp y.hpp
    g++ -c -o x.o x.cpp

y.o: y.cpp y.hpp
    g++ -c -o y.o y.cpp
```

The `x.cpp` file includes `x.hpp` and `y.hpp` while `y.cpp` only includes `y.hpp`. The final executable is `xy`.

The first rule builds the executable from the two object files. The second and third rules builds the two object files, which is what I think you're asking for in the question.

Comment: Can you, please,  show me full version of file because I don't totaly understand  ?